# De Rham cohomology of a quotient manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ a manifold and $G$ a group that acts on X freely, properly, and smoothly. The quotient $X/G$ has a manifold structure such the projection $\pi:X\rightarrow X/G$ is a submersion. My question is: how are related the De Rham´s cohomology groups  of $X$ with the De Rham´s cohomology groups of the quotient?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a spectral sequence going from the cohomology $H^*(G,H^*(X))$ to that of $X/G$. Similarly, the projection map $X\to X/G$ is a fibration, and there is the spectral sequence of that fibration.

Comment: Where can I read about that? Do you know any reference?

Comment: Bott's book on algbraic topology. McCleary's book on spectral sequences.

Comment: What's your goal? What do you want to do with this relationship?

Answer (score 3):

If the group $G$ is **finite**, $\pi ^* = H_k^*(X /G, {\bf R} )\to H_k^*(X, {\bf R})$ is injective. You can prove it by an averaging argument or say that (for the pull back Riemannian metric) the pull back of an harmonic form is harmonic.

In fact $ H_k^*(X/G,{\bf R})\subset  H_k^*(X, {\bf R})$ is the set of $G$-invariant vectors of $H_k^*(X,{\bf R})$ viewed as a finite dimensional representation of $G$.

Another basic result is about the Euler-Poincaré characteristic : $\chi (X/G) \times \vert G \vert= \chi (X)$.